# AWS Named Credential in Salesforce Error (Endpoint needs to be in full URL form)

Tags: namedcredentials, aws

I have an AWS account and two Orgs. I want to link an AWS account to Salesforce with Named Credentials. One Org is of 240 branch and the other is a Sandbox Org that is owned by a customer. I used the 'arn:aws:region:account-number' format for the URL. It works with the 240 Org, but not with the customer Sandbox Org (I get the `URL: Endpoint needs to be in full URL form` error.) Why is that so?

Steps to reproduce for both Orgs:

1. Go to Setup
2. search 'Named Credentials'
3. Add new credentials
4. (Pick Legacy if specified)
5. Choose a name
6. put 'arn:aws:us-west-1:000000000001' for URL
7. Try saving, see error showing on a production Org but not on a 240 Org

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour).  Including a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would be helpful.

Comment: Added more info to the question!

Comment: What's a 240 org?

Comment: 240 is the internal designation for the latest batch of code changes in core. By 240 org I mean an Org created with code from 240 branch of code

Comment: 240 = Winter 23 preview org? If so, then you'll find out shortly if a new Named Credential feature allows ARNs in addition to regular HTTP URLs

Comment: I see error as `Error: Endpoint needs to be in full URL form` in my Summer'22 org and `Error: The Amazon Resource Name (ARN) must be in the format arn:aws:[REGION]:[ACCOUNT_NUMBER] or arn:aws:[REGION] if Username contains your AWS account number.` in Winter'23 org.

Answer (score 0):

You only should put your region in CAPITAL Letter like so:

arn:aws:US-EAST-1:YOUR_ACCOUNT_ID

Reference:

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.ev_relay_create_named_credential.htm&type=5

EDIT:

The URL is case-sensitive, and aws_region is in capital letters. For example, the URL for an account in the US-WEST-2 region has this format: arn:aws:US-WEST-2:XXXXXXXXXXXX. (XXXXXXXXXXXX is a placeholder for the 12-digit AWS account ID.)

Comment: OP stated that it worked with lower case letters for one of the two orgs. How could the small letters then be the reason?

Comment: well, I don't know why, man!, but I have tried to put in lower case and it didn't work. I am just sharing what I have done to fix the problem.

Comment: I have not found any example in what looks like the [pertinent spec](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/APIReference/qs-arn-format.html), but [this document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/APIReference/qs-resource-arns.html) makes it unlikely the lack of capitals is the problem.

Comment: "Look, I spent two hours encountering the same error described in this post. I couldn't find a valid reason for it not to be working, even though I was following the documentation. I found the following post, and in the post, I realized that the ONLY difference was that the region was in uppercase letters. I changed it, and it worked!

Why? I don't know! But it worked.

That's what the community is for: sharing insights."

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.ev_relay_create_named_credential.htm&type=5

Comment: Hey, but this is good stuff! It clearly states that it should be in capitals. I looked at the wrong side. If I came across grumpy, I apologise.  Upvoted.